# How do I create content importing data from an Excel file?

Tags: 6

I am using Drupal 6 and created a custom content type. I have an excel sheet that has more than 2 lacs entry. It is not easy to enter manually.

Is there is any way to this, either programmatically or from the UI?

Comment: there is no taxomony field in content type

Comment: "lakhs"? I have tried to fix your question as best as I could but it was really hard, it was so full of typos. Please pay a little attention -- it was visible not the lack of English knowledge :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Feeds module.

1. Export your excel sheet as CSV with column headings quoting every cell.
2. Download and install the [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module (and optionally [Feeds Tamper](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper)).
3. Create a new Feeds importer to consume the CSV.
   http://example.com/admin/structure/feeds/create
   Set *Fetcher* (change) to **file upload**, *Parser* (change) to **CSV parser** and Processor to Node processor.
4. Map (exactly) your column headings in Node processor mapping.

I've used this with great success in Drupal 7 and once in Drupal 6. PS: Upgrade to D7.